# how to use these debugging flags in my C++ code on VS code (Windows 10)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, windows-10, ide

Code (if required) >>>

```
// two pointer 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main () {
    int arr[] = {3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 15, 16} ;
    int sum = 40 ;
    int i =0;
    int j = *(&arr + 1) - arr - 1 ;
    bool found = false ;
    cout<<j<<endl;

    while ( i<j && found == false) {
        if (arr[i] + arr[j] == sum){
            found = true ;
        }
        else {
            if ( arr[i] + arr[j] < sum){
                i++ ;
            }
            else {
                j-- ;
            }
        }

    }  // end of while
    if (found == true)
    cout<<arr[i]<<"  "<<arr[j]<<endl;


    return 0 ;
}
```

Problem in brief - I cannot compile my small piece of code with the some debugging flags in VS Code using cmd terminal, the debugging flags are : -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -fsanitize=undefined -ftrapv

Details -
my machine - WIndows 10 64 bit
Compiler - GCC C++ compiler (g++) and GDB debugger from mingw-w64
IDE - VS Code
file name - main.cpp

So basically i m new to VS CODE OR any IDE environment. I followed the steps from here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw, to set up my VSCode for build task, debugging main.cpp .VS code configurations, task.json file and launch.json file.

BY compling and running main.cpp through cmd terminal in VS Code using these commands

```
C:\Users\Humble Fool\Desktop\dummy>g++ main.cpp

C:\Users\Humble Fool\Desktop\dummy>.\a.exe
```

(my code gets executed properly as show below)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmO13.png)

But when i went on to compile with these debugging flags, `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` `-fsanitize=undefined` `-ftrapv` through the following command in terminal :

```
C:\Users\Humble Fool\Desktop\dummy>g++ main.cpp -g -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -fsanitize=undefined -ftrapv
```

i got this error message :

```
C:\Users\Humble Fool\Desktop\dummy>g++ main.cpp -g -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG    -fsanitize=undefined -ftrapv
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lubsan        
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So can anyone guide me with a step-by-step guide to compile with those debugging flags ?
If it can be fixed using tasks.json or launch.json file, then will i have to update these two files for every folder that I import in VS Code ?

I m also attaching my tasks.json and launch.json files

tasks.json file  -

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

launch.json file  -

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please don't link to images of code or error messages. Post such things directly *in the question* as *text*.

Comment: ok noted that point.

Comment: Nothing to do with your compiling (or lack thereof), but `int j = *(&arr + 1) - arr - 1 ;` is almost definitely not what you want. You're mixing in values with addresses and then assigning to an int in the end.

Comment: _"But when i went on to compile with these debugging flags, `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -fsanitize=undefined -ftrapv` through the following command in terminal"_ how is this problem related to VS code when the problem occurs in terminal?

Comment: @Thomas Sablik what i did was went to the top of VS Code then Terminal -> New Terminal and a terminal showed up in the bottom as cmd. Hope it clears what i m trying to tell you.

Comment: Then the problem is unrelated to VS code. You built the project from terminal and got an error. It's not related to your VS code configuration. Your compiler doesn't support `-fsanitize=undefined`. That has nothing to do with VS code.

Comment: wait then i tried the other way. After saving my main.cpp file i pressed ctrl + shift + B and got this message in terminal,  `> Executing task: C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -g "c:\Users\Humble Fool\Desktop\dummy\main.cpp" -o "c:\Users\Humble Fool\Desktop\dummy\main.exe" <


Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.`  after that it switched back from Task C/C++ : g++.exe  build active file to cmd  .

Comment: I didn't find anything about MinGW but some posts that Cygwin doesn't support `-fsanitize=undefined`. What's the problem with the other message?

Comment: It seems you are a beginner and VS code can be complicated for beginners. You have to understand how a C++ built process works. I recommend to use a different IDE until you understand better or even better build the project from terminal. Write makefiles or CMake files

Comment: @Thomas Sablik i think you are right because when i compiled using g++ main.cpp  -g -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG  -ftrapv  it compiled properly and an a.exe file was created. but when i used g++ main.cpp -g -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -fsanitize=undefined -ftrapv this gave me this output : `C:\Users\Humble Fool\Desktop\dummy>g++ main.cpp -fsanitize=undefined
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lubsan        
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`

Comment: how can i use  -fsanitize=undefined flag in VS Code ? And why can;t i use this flag ?

Comment: Your compiler doesn't support it. You can use a different compiler. `gcc` is a Linux compiler that was ported to Windows. It's still not completely ported. I don't know Windows so I don't know which compilers on Windows support UB sanitizers.

Comment: CLang will support it ? but  doesn't minGW version 8 support this debugging flag ?

Comment: @Thomas Sablik okay then i will for someone who uses windows to help me out with this. Thnx a lot for your help !

Comment: You can try it with Clang but using Windows you should consider switching to Visual Studio. IMHO if you want to learn C++ use Linux. If you want to code C++ on Windows use Visual Studio.

Comment: you mean switching from VS Code to visual studio ? is visual studio not this much complicated for beginners ?

Comment: Visual Studio comes with its own compiler. It's Microsoft's C++ compiler. AFAIK it supports some sanitizers. But as I said my recommendation is to use Linux (in a virtualization or using Docker) for C++.